# Is Vagrant the right choice for a local development environment (not a local web server)?

Tags: vagrant, development-environment

As far as I understand, Vagrant is used to serve web applications under different server configurations in order to mimic production environments during local development, but is it recommended to use Vagrant to be able to set up local development environments that do not actually run web applications themselves, but are used to write code, install npm packages, compile CSS, etc?

I know that some - if not many - people write code on the host machine, but as I am a heavy terminal user, I would prefer to move my local development environment to a VM which could then be reinstalled in a different machine in a matter of minutes. Whether this is one of the intended use cases for Vagrant seems really confusing to me.

P.S. This Vagrant VM would not run any web applications, i.e. it would not act as a web server, but rather as an isolated environment for development tools like vim, gulp, bower and others. I would prefer to spin up separate Vagrant VMs to serve my web applications.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand the use you wanna have of your VM, but I don't see the point of having a development environment, use it localy and use the VM only to copy it from one machine to another. The main point is (for me at least) to isolate your dev environment from your local environment. But maybe I understood wrong what your intentions were ...

Comment: I'd like to use vagrant to set up my local development environment, but I'm not sure whether it's intended to be used like this.

Answer (score 2):

Using Vagrant to run a development environment that doesn't include running a web server is something I use pretty often, *especially* when a different OS from my host is preferred or required for development. This probably isn't the most common use for Vagrant, but it's a perfectly valid one.

For example, one of our products is Windows based so we use VisualStudio, but our laptops are all Macs. We have a Vagrant Windows all-in-one box which has the IDE, git, and the web server. This makes it trivial for developers to get up and running quickly or throw away their box and repave them.

While this works pretty well, the single box has too many responsibilities - both IDE and web server. We plan to break it out into separate Vagrant boxes, one for VisualStudio/dev environment and the other with a more production like web server configuration. This would also allow us to re-use the VisualStudio Vagrant box elsewhere if needed.

In addition to the Windows example I also have a couple of Linux dev boxes. I have a golang Vagrant dev box and a Kerberos dev box. While I could have just had Boxen configure these for me on my Mac, I felt it was cleaner and easier to have dedicated Vagrant dev boxes.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I have a set up a Vagrant VM running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS that I'm using as a development environment (vim+tmux+git etc). Whenever I need to work on a project I simply spin up a separate Vagrant instance of another VM that is configured to replicate the specific OS and its configuration required for a particular project. This workflow works really well. The reason I've asked the question was because I had the feeling that Vagrant is intended for web server configuration rather than a local dev env. But the latter works too and is a true lifesaver when moving to a new system.

Comment: Also, Sneal, is it safe (security-wise) to store my personal SSH keys that I use on other services inside the Vagrant VM? I'm thinking about sharing the .ssh folder on the host with the VM so that I can ssh into other services from inside the VM.

Comment: Assuming the VM image itself is secure, then I don't see an issue with storing your SSH keys on the guest itself - this is what I do. Someone more knowledgable in this area could probably make a better case for which is more secure, but I assume the truly paranoid would create new guest specific keys.

Comment: "Assuming the VM image itself is secure" - does this mean disallowing remote logins to the VM? I only allow the host to be able to log into my Vagrant VM.

Comment: I've also considered using SSH agent forwarding in my local Vagrant development machine. Is it safe/safer? Would you recommend it? I've read that SSH agent forwarding has some security issues and I'm not sure if this is still relevant while interacting with a local Vagrant VM.

Comment: I think in the context of Vagrant SSH agent forwarding would be secure, but I'm no expert. That sounds like a good superuser question.